# How to change Working Directory when running unit test from Visual Studio Test Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nunit, visual-studio-2022, test-explorer

For my new project, I installed Visual Studio 2022, when my co-workers are still using Visual Studio 2019.

Most of the tests are failing on my computer, and after a bit of troubleshooting, I found out that it is due to a change of working directory when running the tests. Instead of working into the generated `bin` folder or something like that, my tests are executed into the `AppData\Local\Temp` folder:

```
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

> "C:\Users\91002969\AppData\Local\Temp"

=> All the relative paths we are using in the test projects are no longer valid.

For example:

Here is the project structure:

```
Project
|-Fixture
|  \_ NoPalmsTables.IB
\_Project.csproj
```

The file "NoPalmsTables.IB" is not copied to the output directory and has no build action associated. During the test, the following line is executed:

```
var path = Path.GetFullPath("../../Fixtures/NoPalmsTables.IB");
```

In Visual Studio 2022, I get the following results

> "C:\Users\91002969\AppData\Fixtures\NoPalmsTables.IB"

In Visual Studio 2019, my co-worker gets the following result:

> "C:\Users\90026496\PATH_TO_WORKSPACE\src\Project\Fixtures\NoPalmsTables.IB"

My guess is that it is due to the migration to VS2022. Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to run the test in a specific folder instead of `AppData`?

I don't know if it is relevant but we are using NUnit2 to test our application (we are studying the possibility to migrate to version 3). Finally, the application targets .NET 4.7.2.

Comment: The functionality you are describing would be odd I think. I think you have made some assumptions here which may not necessarily be true. Or at least, I can't find any online documentation to any change in behavior for VS 2022 that you are describing, nor would I expect one. I use VS 2022 and my tests are executed in the bin folder as expected, although I use NUnit3.

If you run the tests in VS 2019 to they pass? What kind of errors are you getting when your tests fail?

Comment: @IanSoc yes, my assumptions have frequently proven to be wrong :D. I edited the question with an example of what's happening on my computer and on my co-worker computer.

Comment: I see a git equivilant of turning it off and on again fixed the issue :) Glad to hear it

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I ran a git clean command to completely clean my workspace and ... it suddently works fine ...

Here is the command I used:

```
git clean -d -f -x
```

Not sure of what happened...